# Scraping from an interactive chart

Tags: web-scraping, screen-scraping, scrapy

I would like to retrieve information from charts that shows you the information of a datapoint when you are with the arrow of your mouse on the Y coordinate [The link to an image that shows my situation. The red X is where my mouse was pointing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6XFx.png).

In my mind I wanted to create a scraper that simulates my mouse moving a pixel after another and each time save the data showed.

Can you help my please?
Thank you very much

Comment: What site is that? that site must be loading data in JSON format via an AJAX call or they have data already there in initial response, send me the site link

Comment: Thank you very much. Here is the link https://bitcoinvisuals.com/ln-capacity

Answer (score 1):

They are loading data from https://bitcoinvisuals.com/static/data/data_daily.csv URL as CSV and then passing to the graph

They are using this Javascript code to manipulate data

```
// Iterate through chunk data
for (i = 0; i < data_csv.length; i++) {
    var day = ( data_csv[i].day == "" ? null : new Date(data_csv[i].day).getTime() );
    var btc = ( data_csv[i].capacity_total == "" ? null : +data_csv[i].capacity_total );

    // If btc exists, try to convert
    if (btc) {
        var usd = ( data_csv[i].price_btc == "" ? null : (btc * +data_csv[i].price_btc) );
    }

    // Push to series
    if (day) {
        // If either exists
        if (btc || usd) {
            series_btc.addPoint([day, btc], redraw = false)
            series_usd.addPoint([day, usd], redraw = false)
        }       
    }
}
```

Note that `capacity_total` is the column that exists in that CSV

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much. I am just a noob and I don't have yet much of experience. If I may abuse of your knowledge and kindness a little bit more I found this chart even more difficoult to scrap https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/bitcoin-hashrate.html

Comment: @S.Mrtz dude that is in their source code, see view-source:https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/bitcoin-hashrate.html ... you have to do that on your own, thats how you learn